# Wordpress - Add an anchor tag pointing to a pdf file in a custom directory

Tags: php, wordpress, permalinks

1. I set permalink to using %postname%
2. I created a custom page template, in which I want to add some links that point to PDF files for downloading.
3. I put those pdf files under a custom directory called 'PDF' under the child theme.

The result is that every time I click onto those links, postname will always be added in front of the href link regardless if I'm using absolute or relative path.

How can I add a href in the page template and point to the exactly directory I want it to?

Answer (score 0):

If you are hardcoding the file names and never plan on changing them, then you could call the

get_template_directory()
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_directory

i.e.

`<a href='<?php get_template_directory() ?>/pdf/filename.pdf'>`